# Codeception and Symfony 4: get services in UnitTest

Tags: symfony, codeception

I'm trying to use Codeception with Symfony 4 but I'm not able to grab services within tests ( Unit or Funcional )

I have enable the configuration in test yml file, I have tried to gram services but nothing work.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
actor: UnitTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\Unit
        - Symfony:
            app_path: 'src'
            environment: 'dev'
```

How can I get a services in my test using Symfony Service Container?

I tried with

```
$container = $this->getModule('Symfony')->container;
```

But it does not work. Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Symfony module has not `container` property since Codeception 2.1.8, call `_getContainer` method instead.

```php
$container = $this->getModule('Symfony')->_getContainer();
```